# Example of a quantifier which is not compatible with ordered pairs.

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Let $P(x,y)$ be a binary predicate. I have noticed that the string of quantifiers $\forall x \forall y P(x,y)$ is equivalent to the single quantifier $\forall (x,y) P(x,y)$. Also, $\exists x \exists y P(x,y)$ is equivalent to $\exists (x,y) P(x,y)$. So, I am left to wonder, is there a quantifier $Q$ such that $QxQy P(x,y)$ is not equivalent to $Q(x,y) P(x,y)$? It should not be some sort of exotic quantifier, I am looking for a simple example of a quantifier which is not compatible with ordered pairs.

Comment: Standard first-order logic only defines the two quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$, and no others.    So for your question to make sense, you need to tell us what system of logic you are working in, and what other quantifiers besides $\forall$ and $\exists$ it actually has.  And of those, which ones you consider to be "simple" versus "exotic".  (And for that matter, where you got stuck in attempting to prove or disprove the equivalence for those other quantifiers.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about $\exists!$, the unique existence quantifier? Working in the structure $(\mathbb{N};<)$, we have that $\exists !x\exists !y(x>y)$ is true but $\exists !(x,y)(x>y)$ is obviously false.

Comment: Maybe an even better example is the "there exist two" quantifier: $QxP(x)$ iff there are exactly two $x$ such that $P(x)$. (I guess there's a standard symbol for that but I don't feel like trying to look it up.) Now $QxQyP(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)P(x,y)$ are not only inequivalent, they are incompatible. But I don't know if $Q$ is an "exotic" quantifier. Is there a standard definition of "exotic quantifier"? If not how do we know $\exists!$ isn't "exotic"?

Comment: And I guess this generalises to any count or measure. If x and y are taken from the same measured space $(\Omega, \mu)$, and $\Omega \times \Omega$ is equipped with the product measure, and $p \geq 0$, then define the quantifier $\exists_{\geq p}$ by: "$\exists_{\geq p} x,\, P(x)$" iff $\mu(\{ x | P(x) \}) \geq p$.